# Can I search across my database for tables with a destination column and output the unique domains?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that uses tables to drive reporting.  There are destination columns on various tables that contain email addresses.  I'd like to return, for each table, the table name and list of unique email domains that are in the destination column.

I have a query to search for values in the columns and return the table and column name.  Not sure if this is a good start or not, but it's not quite what I need.  I think I got it from another thread here.

```
DECLARE
   @SearchText varchar(200),
   @Table varchar(100),
   @TableID int,
   @ColumnName varchar(100),
   @String varchar(1000);
   SET @SearchText = '.com';
--modify the variable, specify the text to search for SET @SearchText = 'John';
DECLARE CursorSearch CURSOR
    FOR SELECT name, object_id
        FROM sys.objects
      WHERE type = 'U' and name like 'rp_%';
--list of tables in the current database. Type = 'U' = tables(user-defined) 
OPEN CursorSearch;
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorSearch INTO @Table, @TableID;
WHILE
       @@FETCH_STATUS
       =
       0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE CursorColumns CURSOR
            FOR SELECT name
                  FROM sys.columns
                WHERE
                       object_id
                       =
                       @TableID AND system_type_id IN(167, 175, 231, 239);
        -- the columns that can contain textual data        
--167 = varchar; 175 = char; 231 = nvarchar; 239 = nchar        
OPEN CursorColumns;
        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorColumns INTO @ColumnName;
        WHILE
               @@FETCH_STATUS
               =
               0
            BEGIN
                SET @String = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM '
                            + @Table
                            + ' WHERE '
                            + @ColumnName
                            + ' LIKE ''%'
                            + @SearchText
                            + '%'') PRINT '''
                            + @Table
                            + ', '
                            + @ColumnName
                            + '''';
                EXECUTE (@String);
                FETCH NEXT FROM CursorColumns INTO @ColumnName;
            END;
        CLOSE CursorColumns;
        DEALLOCATE CursorColumns;
        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorSearch INTO @Table, @TableID;
    END;
CLOSE CursorSearch;
DEALLOCATE CursorSearch;
```

Comment: I hope you are patient. Searching every single column that contains text across your entire database is going to be SLOW!!!! Personally I would not use a cursor if I had to do this. I would use sql to build a dynamic sql string and not use loops.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: Also, the correct data type for object names is `sysname` (a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`). A `varchar(100)` could cause unexpected behaviour for object names if they contain characters outside the code page or you have some (very) lengthy object names.

Comment: What's your real question here, because "Can I ...?" in this case can be answered with "yes."

Comment: Do you know the column name in each of the tables that contains the email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're saying is that you have, for example, tableA with a column that contains email addresses.  Then tableB with a column that contains email addresses.

When you're done you want it to look something like this:

Table_Name|emai_part
[tableA , gmail.com]
[tableB , company.com]

If that's right, you can just add text for the table name and use functions to get just the domain name.

```
--replace @str with the field name I added this as a demo 
DECLARE @str as varchar(50)

SET @str = 'email@email.com'

--Use CHARINDEX to get the position of @.  Then add 1 to start at the next character
--User SUBSTRING and LEN to get the string after the starting position

SELECT 'TableA' AS table_name, SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('@',@str,0) + 1,LEN(@str)) -- FROM TableName A
UNION
SELECT 'TableB' AS table_name, SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX('@',@str,0) + 1,LEN(@str)) -- FROM TableName B
```

Comment: Hi Tamara, thank you for the answer.  The hope was I could search the database for tables with a 'destination' column.  Then, get a list of each unique domain within that column for each table - maybe an array or something.

Comment: A destination column as in they provide the value as a parameter?

Comment: I'd probably hard code it in this case; the column is called 'destination'